# Formatting X axis with dates format

Tags: python, date, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I have written code which plots the past seven day stock value for a user-determined stock market over time.
The problem I have is that I want to format the x axis in a **YYMMDD** format.
I also don't understand what `2.014041e7` means at the end of the x axis.

[image: plot]

**Values for x are:**

```
20140421.0, 20140417.0, 20140416.0, 20140415.0, 20140414.0, 20140411.0, 20140410.0
```

**Values for y are:**

```
531.17, 524.94, 519.01, 517.96, 521.68, 519.61, 523.48
```

My code is as follows:

```
mini = min(y)
maxi = max(y)
minimum = mini - 75
maximum = maxi + 75
mini2 = int(min(x))
maxi2 = int(max(x))

plt.close('all')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
pylab.ylim([minimum,maximum])
pylab.xlim([mini2,maxi2])

ax.plot(x, y)
ax.plot(x, y,'ro')
ax.plot(x, m*x + c)
ax.grid()
ax.plot()
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo1.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When plotting your data using your method you are simply plotting your `y` data against numbers (floats) in `x` such as `20140421.0` (which I assume you wish to mean the date 21/04/2014).

You need to convert your data from these floats into an appropriate format for matplotlib to understand. The code below takes your two lists (x, y) and converts them.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

import datetime as dt

# Original data

raw_x = [20140421.0, 20140417.0, 20140416.0, 20140415.0, 20140414.0, 20140411.0, 20140410.0]
y = [531.17, 524.94, 519.01, 517.96, 521.68, 519.61, 523.48]

# Convert your x-data into an appropriate format.

# date_fmt is a string giving the correct format for your data. In this case
# we are using 'YYYYMMDD.0' as your dates are actually floats.
date_fmt = '%Y%m%d.0'

# Use a list comprehension to convert your dates into datetime objects.
# In the list comp. strptime is used to convert from a string to a datetime
# object.
dt_x = [dt.datetime.strptime(str(i), date_fmt) for i in raw_x]

# Finally we convert the datetime objects into the format used by matplotlib
# in plotting using matplotlib.dates.date2num
x = [mdates.date2num(i) for i in dt_x]

# Now to actually plot your data.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Use plot_date rather than plot when dealing with time data.
ax.plot_date(x, y, 'bo-')

# Create a DateFormatter object which will format your tick labels properly.
# As given in your question I have chosen "YYMMDD"
date_formatter = mdates.DateFormatter('%y%m%d')

# Set the major tick formatter to use your date formatter.
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)

# This simply rotates the x-axis tick labels slightly so they fit nicely.
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

The code is commented throughout so should be easily self explanatory. Details on the various modules can be found below:

1. [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#module-datetime)
2. [`matplotlib.dates`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#module-datetime)

[image: Example]