# How can I use xticks function for that?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, matplotlib

I have some data from a csv file and that data is a dictionary whose values are numpy arrays. Here is some part of my data:

```
{'Date': array(['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', ..., '2017-12-29',
   '2017-12-30', '2017-12-31'], dtype='<U11'), 'Year': array([2015, 2015, 2015, ..., 2017, 2017, 2017]), 'Month': array([ 1,  1,  1, ..., 12, 12, 12]), 'Day': array([ 1,  2,  3, ..., 29, 30, 31]), 'Consumption': array([1111.336 , 1300.884 , 1265.271 , ..., 1295.0875, 1215.449 ,
   1107.1149]), 'Wind': array([325.128, 603.558, 462.953, ..., 584.277, 721.247, 721.176]), 'Solar': array([17.079,  7.758,  7.236, ..., 29.854,  7.467, 19.98 ])}
```

Then, according to that data, I plotted a graph whose x values are dates and y values are consumption, wind and solar information from the data. Let me show you my graph and code:

```
plt.plot(data['Date'], data['Consumption'], label= 'Consumption')
plt.plot(data['Date'] , data['Wind'], label= 'Wind')
plt.plot(data['Date'] , data['Solar'], label='Solar')
plt.legend()
```

[image: My Graph]

Here is my problem. I need to use xticks function to put the month and year information onto the x axis. For example, when my y values show the information of '2015-01-01' date, I need to put 'Jan15' string onto the x axis. I need to do that for all first days of months like 'Feb15' ..... 'Dec17'. The result should be like that:

[image: Result Graph]

Can someone help me about that?

Comment: Lots of examples on SO. You have to set the Locator (seemingly every 30 days) and use the DateFormatter. Because I am too lazy to find an exact duplicate, I will link to an [answer of mine with further links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65343940/8881141)

Comment: I recommend converting them to `datetime` than `matplotlib` distributes them automatically on the axis and you can specify the format with `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('mmm%dd'))`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219218/formatting-x-axis-with-dates-format-matplotlib#23223250)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
Without any other modules, you can simply use a `dict` or `list` to convert month written in numbers into letters. Use `str.split` to separate month and date.
An example:

```py
a = '2015-01-01'
split_a = a.split('-')
# split_a will be: ["2015", "01", "01"]
```

---

My approach would be using the module `datetime` ([doc here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)).

1. Create a list to hold the strings for xtick.
2. Use `strptime()` to convert `str` into a `datetime` object, then use `strftime()` to convert `datetime` object into a `str` with the format you want.
3. Use `plt.xticks([where to draw the ticks], [what shows up in the plot])`

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten to add whether I cannot use any module and library except matplotlib and numpy

Comment: @captaingb I have edited my answer, you can check.